# View override and Recent Items list

Tags: visualforce, page-override, recentlyviewed

I noticed when I load a record for an object that has its View overridden with a Visualforce page, it does not put this record into the "Recently Viewed" list.

Is there any way to put this record into the Recently Viewed list?

Comment: Have you tried querying it in the constructor "for view"? I guess that might be impractical to have to do on every page, but a workaround nevertheless.

Comment: That was what I was looking for!  Please make it an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying the record "for view" will cause it to appear on the recent items list. You can do this in the constructor for the Visualforce page. Here's an example:

```
public MyPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    SObject[] record = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :controller.getId() FOR VIEW];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from sfdcfox, if you have a tab created for the object, it will show in the recent items list even without requiring FOR VIEW.